# ConnectionFailure user error ( RTS doesn't support multiple OS threads ( use ghc -threaded when linking ) )

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I run into the below error when running a executable I built with `stack build`:

```
 ( ConnectionFailure user error ( RTS doesn't support multiple OS threads ( use ghc -threaded when linking ) ) )
```

Surprisingly this executable works on my machine, but not on another...

What is the cause of this error? Why does it have different behavior on two machines?

The machine it works on uses an AMD CPU, while the other non working one uses an Intel CPU.

---

Within my `~/stack/config.yaml` I have: `ghc-build: nopie` due to https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2712. I've just removed this now and trying a `stack build` again...

Comment: Have you tried doing as it says and compiling with `-threaded`?

Comment: That seems to have done it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ghc-options: -threaded
```

Add above to cabal file to enable this option.

Comment: Most of these have nothing to do with threading. All that's needed here is the `-threaded` option as mentioned in the error message; The `-rtsopts` is needed for parsing of RTS arguments.